# VBA Recursion Method - Exit Function Not Exiting

Tags: vba, recursion, pass-by-reference

Why does this function not exit? I've tried both Exit Function and Exit For. After I reach the Ubound(arr) statement i resets to i = 0 and the call stack reverts to the End Select statement thereafter the For Loop begins again. This must be from the recursion line I execute?

```
Function AddArrToObj(ByRef arr As Variant, ByRef obj As Object, Optional ByVal i As Integer = 0)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Select Case VBA.TypeName(obj)
            Case "Collection"
                obj.Add arr(i)
            Case "Dictionary"
                obj.Add i + 1 & " " & arr(i), arr(i)
            Case "Nothing"
                Set obj = New VBA.Collection
                Call AddArrToObj(arr, obj) 'Recursion
        End Select
        'Add Watch for i = 3 break on True
        'Why does this function not exit appropriately?
        If Not IsEmpty(obj) And i = UBound(arr) Then Exit Function
    Next i
End Function


Public Sub TestSO()
Dim collA       As VBA.Collection
Dim cmdStr      As String
cmdStr = "StackOverflow is a website."
arr = VBA.Split(cmdStr, " ")

    Call AddArrToObj(arr, collA)

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not obj is Nothing And...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using recursion, but it's needlessly complicated. As a rule of thumb, you should only use recursion over iteration when the recursive algorithms are much easier to both read and write. Otherwise, you should use iteration due to the potential for stackoverflow errors using recursion. That being said, here's a solution using recursion. I modified your code a bit to both work using recursion and iterate through a returned collection object.:

```
    Function AddArrToObj(ByRef arr As Variant, ByRef obj As Object, Optional ByVal i As Integer = 0)
    If obj Is Nothing And i <> 0 Then
        Set obj = New Collection
    End If

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Select Case VBA.TypeName(obj)
            Case "Collection"
                obj.Add arr(i)
            Case "Dictionary"
                obj.Add i + 1 & " " & arr(i), arr(i)
            Case "Nothing"
                Set obj = AddArrToObj(arr, obj, 1) 'Recursion
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next i

    Set AddArrToObj = obj
End Function

Public Sub TestSO()
Dim collA       As VBA.Collection
Dim cmdStr      As String
Dim arr() As String
Dim obj As Object
Dim elem As Variant

cmdStr = "StackOverflow is a website."
arr = VBA.Split(cmdStr, " ")

Set obj = AddArrToObj(arr, collA)

For Each elem In obj
    Debug.Print elem
Next elem

End Sub
```